# How to get the model and action name of the calling action

Tags: cakephp

I have a log feature in my project that tracks all changes to a couple of different models.  Say, whenever a user or an admin edits an account.  Or when a user creates a new record.  All those actions get recorded in the log table.

I would like to have the log model retrieve the model name and action name by itself in a beforeSave action when called to save a new record.   I call it now from a controller action making the save like this:

```
$this->Log->save(array(
    'user'=>$this->Auth->user('id'), 
    'model'=>$this->name, 
    'action'=>$this->action));
```

I would love to be able to shorten it down to:

```
$this->Log->save();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found alkerman's wonderful [LogableBehavior](http://bakery.cakephp.org/users/view/alkemann) and it is working like a charm.  No need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd be inclined to either write a method on app_controller such as

`saveLog()` 
which calls

`$this->Log->save($uma_array)`

or simplify your existing construct by doing

`$this->Log->save($this)`

and untangling the data inside the method.

EDIT:

Of course, the best way to do this would be to use observable behaviour using teknoid's pattern: http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2009/08/10/observer-pattern-the-cakephp-way/
It's not that difficult to implement.

Comment: It is better to write save() method in the Log model.